# Web App Main Menu Should Contain All Commands

Tags: web-app, menu

Looking for insight or sources that might support that an application's main menu should contain or at least attempt to contain all commands available in the application.

Any sources to support this? Strong arguments against the notion?

This would be an application that is set up in the traditional sense with File View Window etc.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any sources that strongly supports or is against the notion of the application's main menu containing all the commands available.

But from my research, the best practice is to group commands appropriately. Meaning that it should be intuitive for the user to navigate your applications.

Here are the references that I found useful:

https://balsamiq.com/learn/ui-control-guidelines/menu-bars/
https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/information-architecture/website-navigation-design-best-practices/
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/menus/menu-bar-menus/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the references. 
I agree with grouping commands appropriately as one of the main guiding principles for menus. So that users can find what they are looking for.